# Print formatting to file in Python

Tags: python, string, formatting, format, python-unicode

I wish to write to a file in a formatted way. I have been searching how I can do this, and the best solution I have managed to get is this:

```
write_to_file.write('{:20} {:20} {:3}\n'.format(w[0][0], w[0][1], w[1]))
```

However, when I do this I do not get precise formatting.

```
det                  er                     6
er                   det                    5
den                  er                     5
du                   kan                    4
hva                  er                     3
har                  en                     3
er                   død                   3
å                   gjøre                 3
jeg                  vil                    3
har                  vi                     3
et                   dikt                   2
når                 du                     2
det                  var                    2
må                  være                  2
kan                  skrive                 2
hva                  gjør                  2
ha                   et                     2
jeg                  har                    2
du                   skal                   2
vi                   kan                    2
jeg                  kan                    2
en                   vakker                 2
er                   du                     2
når                 man                    2
får                 jeg                    2
```

I get things printed in the fashion above. I need everything to align perfectly.

Comment: You might find this question interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225441

Comment: Wild guess: you haven't stripped the white space from the items.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like the accented characters are treated as taking up two spaces.

Comment: This is probably a result of combining characters taking up an extra code point.  NFC will help, but it won't fix weird things like [n-umlaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-diaeresis).

Comment: Python 2.x strikes again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because [you're still dealing with bytes](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/). Once you start dealing with actual characters you'll find that they align perfectly.

```
write_to_file.write('{:20} {:20} {:3}\n'.format(u'å', u'gjøre', u'3'))
```

Comment: When I do that I get the error message: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: That means that you have other problems in your code, not that this solution is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The DataFrame command in the Pandas library would also be worth looking into.