# How do you get the display width of combined Unicode characters in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

In Python 3, Unicode strings are supposed to kindly give you the number of Unicode characters, but I can't figure out how to get the final display width of a string given that some characters combine.

Genesis 1:1 -- בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ

```
>>> len('בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ')
60
```

But the string is only 37 characters wide.  Normalization doesn't solve the problem because the vowels (dots underneath the larger characters) are distinct characters.

```
>>> len(unicodedata.normalize('NFC', 'בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ'))
60
```

As a side note: the `textwrap` module is totally broken in this regard, aggressively wrapping where it shouldn't.  `str.format` seems similarly broken.

- Similar question that was marked as a duplicate:
  [Display width of unicode strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225441/display-width-of-unicode-strings-in-python)
- The question it was marked as a duplicate of only addresses normalization:
  [Normalizing Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode)

Comment: Counting grapheme clusters might not be enough e.g., [different fonts  may lead to different text sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2922295/4279)

Comment: Even if we're guaranteed a monospace font?

Comment: Follow the link, try the code and see for yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of solutions using the third party `uniseg`, as suggested by @bobince:

```
>>> from uniseg.graphemecluster import grapheme_cluster_breakables
>>> sum(grapheme_cluster_breakables('בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ'))
37
>>>
>>> from uniseg.graphemecluster import grapheme_clusters
>>> list(grapheme_clusters('בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְ  הָאָרֶץ'))
['בְּ', 'רֵ', 'א', 'שִׁ', 'י', 'ת', ',', ' ', 'בָּ', 'רָ', 'א', ' ', 'אֱ', 'לֹ', 'הִ', 'י', 'ם', ',', ' ', 'אֵ', 'ת', ' ', 'הַ', 'שָּׁ', 'מַ', 'יִ', 'ם', ',', ' ', 'וְ', 'אֵ', 'ת', ' ', 'הָ', 'אָ', 'רֶ', 'ץ']
>>> len(list(grapheme_clusters('בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַי , ואֵת הָאָרֶץ')))
37
```

This looks like the proper way to do it.

Here's an example that patches up `textwrap`.  Solutions for patching up other modules should be similar.

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> text = 'בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ'
>>> print(textwrap.fill(text, width=40))  # bad, aggressive wrapping
בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת
הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ
>>> import uniseg.graphemecluster
>>> def new_len(x):
...     if isinstance(x, str):
...         return sum(1 for _ in uniseg.graphemecluster.grapheme_clusters(x))
...     return len(x)
>>> textwrap.len = new_len
>>> print(textwrap.fill(text, width=40))  # Good wrapping
בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ
```

Comment: You could also use `regex` module: `count_user_perceived_characters = lambda text: len(regex.findall(r'\X', text))`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Neat!  That project says it intends to replace `re`.  Do you have any idea if it actually will?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the combining characters, which Python counts as distinct when computing `__len__`, but merge into a single printed character.

To find out whether a character is a combining character, we can use the [unicodedata module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html):

> `unicodedata.combining(unichr)`
>
> Returns the canonical combining class assigned to the Unicode character unichr as integer. Returns 0 if no combining class is defined.

A naive solution is to just strip out any characters with a non-zero combining class. This leaves characters that stand on their own, and should give us a string with a 1-to-1 mapping between visible and underlying characters.
*(I am a Unicode novice, and it’s probably more complicated than that. There are subtleties with combining characters and grapheme extenders which I don’t really understand, but don’t seem to matter for this particular string.)*

So I came up with this function:

```
import unicodedata

def visible_length(unistr):
    '''Returns the number of printed characters in a Unicode string.'''
    return len([char for char in unistr if unicodedata.combining(char) == 0])
```

which returns the correct length for your string:

```
>>> visible_length('בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ')
37
```

This is probably not a complete solution for all Unicode strings, but depending on what subset of Unicode you’re working with, this may be enough for your needs.

Comment: If you need the full Unicode grapheme cluster segmentation algorithm or line-splitting then that's a bit more complicated—see third-party modules such as uniseg.

Comment: +1.  This had occured to me, but when I played around with unicodedata.combining and saw that it returned a wide range of values, I got pretty intimidated, but maybe it's suitable for my purposes.  Thanks.  Hopefully someone can propose an even more robust solution.