how do I set align the strings with Chinese characters in Java?
The following code is designed to print three strings, with each '(' character put at the 11th position in its respective line, ensuring vertical alignment of the '(' characters.
        System.out.printf("%1$10s (%2$2s)\n", "孙悟空", 1);
        System.out.printf("%1$10s (%2$2s)\n", "唐僧", 2);
        System.out.printf("%1$10s (%2$2s)\n", "hello", 3);


However, the code fails to align them properly due to the presence of Chinese characters. How can this issue be resolved?
it doesn't have to use String.format(), any other java API is also appreciated.

There is the correct number of spaces, but it looks like your display font isn't fixed width per character so they won't line up in the display.

add a TAB \t before the (

Related, unanswerable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138083/how-to-generate-a-phantom-string-for-a-unicode-string-consisting-of-whitespac
I still don't know of any systematic solution.

The text doesn't look "aligned" because the widths of the characters are not the same. The Chinese characters takes up more horizontal space than the other characters.
This can probably be fixed by just using a font that displays everything in the same width, though I don't know of such a font.
This won't work with every single code point in Unicode, but if you are only working with the Latin alphabet and Chinese characters, I would suggest converting whatever String.format outputs to full width characters. You can do this easily with a Transliterator from ICU4J.
Example:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var s1 = String.format("%1$10s (%2$2s)", "孙悟空", 1);
    var s2 = String.format("%1$10s (%2$2s)", "唐僧", 2);
    var s3 = String.format("%1$10s (%2$2s)", "hello", 3);
    System.out.println(toFullWidth(s1));
    System.out.println(toFullWidth(s2));
    System.out.println(toFullWidth(s3));
}

static String toFullWidth(String s) {
    Transliterator t = Transliterator.getInstance("Halfwidth-Fullwidth");
    return t.transliterate(s);
}

Output:
　　　　　　　孙悟空　（　１）
　　　　　　　　唐僧　（　２）
　　　　　ｈｅｌｌｏ　（　３）

If you think it is overkill to use ICU4J just for this, you can always hard-code your own Map<Character, Character> for the characters you care about. See the list of full width characters on Wikipedia.
